# How do i get a DocumentSnapshot of a map and retrieve the length of the map?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to get the length of Map<String, bool> upvotes as shown in the picture of firebase and display the number of upvotes for a post. How do i get the documentSnapshot of the field in the first place? I have a snippet of the code as shown but there is an error.

```
class Post { //for forums
  String title;
  String content;
  String timestamp;
  String imageurl;
  String username;
  String profilePicture;
  String documentid;
  String ownerid;
  Map<String, bool> saved = {};
  Map<String, bool> upvotes = {};
  //Map<String, bool> saved;


  Post(
    this.title,
    this.content,
    this.timestamp,
    this.imageurl,
    this.username,
    this.profilePicture,
    this.documentid,
    this.ownerid,
    this.saved,
    this.upvotes
    //this.image
  );

  Post.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) : 
  title = snapshot["title"],
  content = snapshot['content'],
  timestamp = snapshot['timestamp'],
  imageurl = snapshot['imageurl'],
  username = snapshot['username'],
  profilePicture = snapshot['profilePicture'],
  documentid = snapshot['documentid'],
  upvotes = snapshot['upvotes'], //gives error as shown in red image
  ownerid = snapshot['ownerid'],
  saved = snapshot['saved'];//gives error as shown in red image
}
```

[image: Firebase image]
[image: Code and error image]

Comment: Please don't use images of code. Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then format it as code. This helps others more easily read and test your code. Can you please show the error message? You'll most likely need the _data_ property from _DocumentSnapshot_ to access the data in the snapshot. Check out the following [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html).

Comment: To get the number of votes, have you tried to access the snapshot of the field _upvotes_ to get the length of the object?

Comment: @sllopis Hi, i have included the code for the Post class. i tried to access the snapshot as shown but snapshot['upvotes'] gives an error 'type InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> is not a subtype of Map<String, bool>

Comment: Have you tried changing the data type of the variables _saved_ and _upvotes_ to _Map<String, dynamic>_? What do you see then?